# Help in deriving a equation on logarithm of formal power series.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, power-series

This question refers to the equation 1.54 in the link https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.03788.pdf . In short for a power series
$$x=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{i_1,...,i_k\in\{{1,...d\}}}\lambda_{i_1,....i_k}e_{i_1}...e_{i_k}$$

for which $\lambda_0>0$ define its logarithm as the power series given by
$$x=\log(\lambda_0)+\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\dfrac{(-1)^n}n(1-\dfrac{x}\lambda_0)^{\otimes n}$$

Form the above it says that for a real $\lambda$ for the series

$$x=1+\sum\limits_{k\geq1}\dfrac{(\lambda)^k}{!k}e_1^{\otimes k}$$ Then it says that $\log x=\lambda e_1$

the question how it derived $\log x=\lambda e_1$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean $$\log(x)=\log(\lambda_0)+\log(1+(\dfrac{x}\lambda_0-1))=\log(\lambda_0)+\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\dfrac{(-1)^n}n(1-\dfrac{x}\lambda_0)^{ n}$$

Comment: Then $u=v$ implies $\log (u) = \log(v)$ and for $v=\exp(\lambda e_1)$ we get $\log v=\lambda e_1$.

Comment: @reuns It must be something like that, but I am still missing something. I will try to figure it out.

Comment: @reuns thank you so much. I have never guessed that we are using the usual log(1+x) expansion.